# sphinx4 doesnt work in raspberry pi correctly(no microfon available)

Tags: sphinx4

I try sphinx4 in raspberry pi an i am getting "microphone is not available" message. Also pulseAudio VolumeControl program in raspberry show singal input from the USB pnp microphone. What's the problem?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Java on rpi doesn't use pulseaudio, it uses alsa. Overall, sphinx4 is a bad idea on rpi, it's too slow. Use pocketsphinx, either from Python or from Java.

Comment: if i use ubuntu on rpi, do i encounter same problem?

Comment: ubuntu is not quite relevant